# Polynomial time algorithms for excepresion

Tags: algorithm

i need to design an algorithm that accepts as input a positive integer k, and finds out the number of arrangements of k objects following the relations = and <.
example: if k = 3, then the thirteen possible arrangements are:

```
x=y=z
x=y<z
x<y=z
x<y<z
x<z<y
x=z<y
y<x=z
y<x<z
y<z<x
y=z<x
z<x<y
z<y<x
z<x=y
```

the algorithm should work for any k, and should run in polynomial time.

Comment: What language? What have you tried already? Post some code if you're able.

Comment: im try to write a pseudo code

Comment: the algorithm work as if k = 3, then the thirteen possible arrangements are:
x=y=z, x=y<z, x<y=z, x<y<z, x<z<y, x=z<y, y<x=c, y<x<z, y<z<x, y=z<x, z<x<y, and z<y<x.

Comment: could you explain more?

Comment: the algorithm accept k number and try to compare them as example above!

Comment: Btw, the number of possible expressions is the according [Ordered Bell Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number). Thus, there cannot be a polynomial time algorithm.

Comment: What it appears that you are asking is the number of possible different orderings of N numbers based on two relations - the reflexive equality relation, and the non-reflexive ordering "less than" relation - where you can have, for two specific numbers `n` and `m`, exactly one of `n = m`, or `n < m`, or `m < n`. It seems that that should be calculable fairly straight-forwardly, but it's a bit more of a combinatorics question than it is programming, so the Math SE might be a better place to ask...

Comment: @NicoSchertler yes its the thirteen i think!!

Comment: @twalberg how can solve it with polynomial time !do you have any idea

Comment: The high-level idea is to calculate every possible partitioning and then permute partitions within a partitioning. Elements within a partition will be compared by `=` and partitions will be compared by `<`. But as mentioned, there can't be a polynomial time algorithm.

Comment: what about using divide and conquer algorithm!?! or graph it will still the same polynomial time

Comment: Throwing arbitrary buzz words at the problem does not make it less complex. Unless you can prove that the Ordered Bell numbers are bounded by a polynomial, there is no chance that a polynomial time algorithm exists.

Comment: @Nico Schertler: Listing all of the orderings may take more than a polynomial amount of time, but you can count them in much less time, using one of the many recurrences on the page you linked.

Comment: @NicoSchertler A sequence of numbers does not need to be bounded by a polynomial (or anything else for that matter) in order to be calculated in polynomial time. Factorials are not bounded even by an exponential curve, yet they can be calculated in linear time... Enumerating the items being counted by the sequence is a different matter entirely... But I believe the OP just wants to calculate the number, not enumerate all the possible relations...

Comment: Oh, just realized that only the number is needed, not the actual expressions.

Comment: yes, the algorithm to find number of arrangements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following C# code is based on the recurrence relation from the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number):

```
a(n) = Sum {i from 1 to n} (n i) a(n - i)
```

The algorithm uses Dynamic Programming to iteratively calculate the binomial coefficients and the Ordered Bell Numbers. The number of possible expressions with `k` variables is the `k-th` Ordered Bell Number:

```cs
int GetNumberOfExpressions(int k)
{
    //Holds Ordered Bell Numbers calculated so far
    int[] a = new int[k + 1];

    //Contains one row of Pascal's triangle
    int[] binomial = new int[k + 1];

    //Initialize the recurrence
    a[0] = 1;
    binomial[0] = 1;

    //Successively calculate a_1 thru a_k
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; ++i)
    {
        //calculate i-th row of Pascal's triangle
        binomial[i] = 1;
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 1; --j)
            binomial[j] = binomial[j] + binomial[j - 1];

        //calculate a_i
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
            a[i] += binomial[j] * a[i - j];
    }

    return a[k];
}
```

The time complexity of this algorithm is `O(k^2)` and the space complexity is `O(k)`.